# Norm of a continuous linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $A$ be a separable Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{a_n\}_1^\infty$ and $\{x_n\}$ a sequence s.t. $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty||x_n||^2<\infty$.

> 1. How do I show that there exists a continuous map $f:A\rightarrow A$ with $fe_n=x_n$?
> 2. How do I show that $f$ is unique?
> 3. What is an upper bound for $||f||$?

What I know:
1. For continuity I think we need $||fx||\leq C||x||$ for a constant $C$ and all $x\in A$. How would I show this?
2. I think we have to suppose here that there exists a $g$ s.t. $ge_n=x_n$ and show that $g=f$. How does this go?
3. The norm of a linear operator is $\sup\{||fx||:||x||\leq1\}$. So I think we will have to express the upper bound of $||f||$ in terms of $x_n$, but I don't quite see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If $f$ exists using linearity and continuity it must satisfy: $$f:y:=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}y_na_n\mapsto\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}y_nx_na_n.$$
- $f$ is well-defined, since using Parseval's identity: $$\|f(y)\|^2=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\|y_nx_n\|^2\leqslant\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\|x_n\|^2\times\|y\|^2<\infty.$$
  By the way, one see that $f$ is continuous and one has: $$\|f\|\leqslant\sqrt{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\|x_n\|^2}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. How does uniqueness follow?

Comment: For uniqueness note that $x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_ne_n$ for unique reals $\lambda_n$, so if $f_1,~f_2$, as stated, existed, by linearity and continuity: $f_1(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_nf_1(e_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_nf_2(e_n)=f_2(x).$

Comment: Even easier, the first point of my answer gives uniqueness. If $f$ exists, it must be defined as above. It is what we called in French: "raisonnement par analyse-synthèse" (reasoning by analysis-synthesis).

Comment: @C.Falcon Just a typo [it must satisfies]---->[it must satisfy] (too small to edit your post).